# How to change bottom layout constraint in iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have scroll view as @IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
```

I want to change the

```
"Bottom space to: Bottom Layout Guide"
```

constraint programmatically.

```
First Item : Bottom Layout Guide.Top
Relation : Equal
Second Item: Scroll View.Bottom
Constant: 0 -> 50 // (I want to change this programmatically)
Priority: 1000
Multiplier: 1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Take the constraint as `IBOutlet` of `NSLayoutConstraint`.

[image]

Set the constraint outlets and change `constant` value by :

```
self.sampleConstraint.constant = 20
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Where is the best place to change it?

Answer (score 22):

If you are adding constraint programatically like this:

```
var constraintButton = NSLayoutConstraint (item: buttonPlay, 
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
                                           toItem: self.view, 
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0)
// Add the constraint to the view
self.view.addConstraint(constraintButton)
```

Then you can update it this way:

```
self.constraintButton.constant = 50
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

And if you want that with animation you can do it this way:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
    self.constraintButton.constant = 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Remember to do buttonPlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and also to set height and width constraints

Answer (score 7):

Create an `IBOutlet` for your constraint:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomContraint;
```

And when you need to change it call:

```
bottomContstraint.constant = //your value
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Also you can animate constraint change like that:

```
bottomContstraint.constant = //your value

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```