# How to resize the UIImageView when tapped on?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to play around with the UIImageView. I want something that when I tap the image, it makes the image 2x its size (always make it twice the size so if I tap more than once it keeps getting bigger).

This is what I currently have and I am not sure how to build the `handlePan` function that I originally wanted to use. I used the pan gesture because I don't know how to approach the tap gesture specifically. If my code is not on the right direction, please feel free to suggest what would work best. I would really appreciate any input.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView1: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesterRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan)) //handlePan is the tap function I am trying to build
        ImageView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        ImageView1.addGestureRecognizer(gesterRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a pan gesture when all you need is a tap gesture?

Comment: Confusing question. Maybe I can help. First, a question or two. Why are you using a **pan** gesture when your question addresses - I think correctly - a **tap** gesture? I'm thinking this is the actual issue. Maybe something related to dealing with tapping *and then* panning on an image? Second, what is your *specific* issue? Having the tap (or pan) recognized? Increasing the size of the image view?

Comment: I would suggest keeping you imageView Horizontally and vertically center aligned with IBoutlets for NSLayoutConstraints of your imageView's width and heights. refer this answer for how to get IBOutlets for constraints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087809/how-to-change-bottom-layout-constraint-in-ios-swift

Comment: @dfd, Hi, I updated the question!

Comment: Adding to my comment is @Harshal. It addresses auto layout constraints. You've neither included anything suggesting it is auto layout nor have you actually included this `handlePan` function you referenced.

Comment: @dfd I have not build the handlepan. I want to know how to build it. Sorry if it is unclear. I just want to achieve the end goal.

Comment: Here's my best guess. First consider the difference between **pan** and **tap**. I'm not talking the *concept*, Consider the iOS *implementation*. Try things out. I believe a "tap" would be acknowledged in the OS long before a "pan". (Play with it. And consider the important difference between  tp, a long press, and a pan - which may be confused in the OS with a long press **or** tap.)

Comment: Honestly? I think you only want a tap if all you really need is to increase a size of a `UIImageView`. Next? Let us know if you are using auto layout. It sounds like you want **the view** - probably a UIImageView - to double it's "frame" size. At which point you want to make sure the view's `.contentMode` is set correctly and then, well, double the frame size.

Comment: Finally, I'd break this down into pieces. (If you already haven't.) Code the gestures you wish for. Make sure they are recognized in sequence. And *then* work on doubling the image size. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, first of all you need a tap gesture recognizer instead of pan gesture one. In following code you will be able to double the width and height of image each time a user tap's on imageView.

In this implementation I wanted to animate the transition with 0.5 seconds, which is not necessary but it might look better to do it this way. Also assuming that you want image to be at center at all times, you need to set center to frame's center so it wont float around as the frame of image changes. But if you wish to have a different layout or positioning, you need to update the following line:

```
self.imageView.center = self.view.center
```

Also you need to enable imageView's user interaction property, by setting it true.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


@objc func handleTap() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.imageView.frame.size.height *= 2
        self.imageView.frame.size.width *= 2
        self.imageView.center = self.view.center
    }
}

}
```